# UIButton does not change title

Tags: swift

I want to change the buttons title on clicking the button:

```
func dispatchStatusButton(title title:String, backgroundColor:UIColor) {
    self.btnDispatchStatus.setTitleWithoutAnimation(title.uppercaseString)
    self.btnDispatchStatus.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    self.btnDispatchStatus.kern(2.0)
}
```

When I call the function:

```
// Set Button
self.dispatchStatusButton(title: "Inaktiv", backgroundColor: UIColor(red: 40.0/255.0, green: 51.0/255.0, blue: 57.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0))
```

Nothing happens and I have some feeling my kerning function is the reason, but I don't see why:

```
extension UIButton {
    func setTitleWithoutAnimation(title:String?) {
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
        setTitle(title, forState: .Normal)
        layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }

    func kern(kerningValue:CGFloat) {
        let attributedText =  NSAttributedString(string: self.titleLabel!.text!, attributes: [NSKernAttributeName:kerningValue, NSFontAttributeName:self.titleLabel!.font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:self.titleLabel!.textColor])
        self.setAttributedTitle(attributedText, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: My approach with this kind of problems is to simplify the code as much as possibile and gradually reintroduce lines of code. Have you tried without the `UIView.setAnimationsEnabled` calls?

Comment: I now figured out that the kern function is the problem. as soon as I deactivate it again it works. But why is it not refreshing the text when using it?

Comment: Look at my answer, I tested it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `self.titleLabel.text` property gets updated in the following layout pass. That's why you set the title through `setTitle(:forState:)` function, and not to the label directly. In your kern function you reference to it when it is still not updated. Try the following:

```
func kern(kerningValue:CGFloat) {
    let title = self.titleForState(.Normal) ?? "" // This gets the new value
    let attributedText =  NSAttributedString(string: title, attributes: [NSKernAttributeName:kerningValue, NSFontAttributeName:self.titleLabel!.font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:self.titleLabel!.textColor])
    self.setAttributedTitle(attributedText, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```